# Tkinter - How would I create buttons in a new window, which has been created by a function being called? Python 3

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def begin():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("main window")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")  
    return #How would a button be placed in this window made by this function?

root = Tk()
root.title("Start up page")
root.geometry("1920x1080")


BeginButton = Button(app, text = "Begin", command=begin, bg="green")
BeginButton.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)
BeginButton.config(height = 10, width = 30 )

root.mainloop()
```

How would I create new buttons in the new window, if the new window is being made by, in this case a function known as "begin".

Any response would be much appreciated!

Comment: name you new window different to the first one, and use `Toplevel()` instead, then you must define the parent of the buttons like `Button(root2, text = ...)`

Comment: The literal answer to your question, even if you solved the problem mentioned by @user3666197, is "you can't". What you want to do is `return root`, so your caller can store the result somewhere and use that to add buttons to it. (Also note that you don't have anything named `app`, and that since your button is the thing actually calling `begin` it doesn't make much sense to add it to the window created by `begin`…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is to modify the root window rather than create a new one.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root.title("Start up page")
        root.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.beginB = Button(root, text="Begin", command=self.begin,
                        bg="green", height=10, width=30)
        self.beginB.grid(sticky = W)
    def begin(self):
        root.title("main window")
        self.beginB.destroy()
        del self.beginB
        self.goB = Button(root, text='Go on', command=self.go_on,
                                bg='red')
        self.goB.grid(sticky=E)
    def go_on(self):
        self.label = Label(root, text="you have continued")
        self.label.grid(row=1, sticky=S)

App()
root.mainloop()
```

An advantage of defining a class is that you can make forward references. In your code, you had to define the begin function before you create the begin button.  With a class, I could put it after **init**, which to me is a more natural order.  It is ofter the case that the initialization code calls or binds more than one function.